# Laravel 5.4 get relations from collection

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

This is the result in tinker
[image]I have the next eloquent query with relations, what I want to do is get 'solicitud' array from the collection, is it possible ?

```
$requests = Request_conversation::with(['solicitud', 'solicitud.reservation', 'solicitud.detail.subDetails'])->
                where('readed', '=', 0)
                ->whereHas('solicitud', function($q)use($user){
                    $q->where('idUsuario','=', $user);
                })
                ->skip($inicio)
                ->take($elementos)
                ->groupBy('solicitud')
                ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->get();
```

Comment: `$requests->solicitud` will contain a collection. You can apply [`toArray()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-toarray) to it to get the array of your solicituds.

Comment: If I try $requests->solicitud this is the response. Property [solicitud] does not exist on this collection instance.

Comment: Try to remove the `groupBy('soilicitud')` and to apply it after : `$requests->socilitud->groupBy('solicitud')->toArray();`

Comment: The same. Property [solicitud] does not exist on this collection instance.

Comment: So you should give a try to `php artisan tinker` and play to try to find your solicitud relation. Tell us what `Request_conversation::with('solicitud')->get()` gives you, and if your property `soliticitud` is set or is null (could be a malformed relationship on you model `Request_conversation`).

Answer (score 0):

you can by make the following:

```
$requests = Request_conversation::with(['solicitud', 'solicitud.reservation', 'solicitud.detail.subDetails'])->
            where('readed', '=', 0)
            ->whereHas('solicitud', function($q)use($user){
                $q->where('idUsuario','=', $user);
            })
            ->skip($inicio)
            ->take($elementos)
            ->groupBy('solicitud')
            ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->get()->map(function($items){
              return $items->solicitud;});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well regarding `solicitud` relation , something like `$requests->solicitud` won't work because the relation is on single model, not a collection of it.
So if you want to retreive `solicitud`, you need to iterate on `$requests`. **You might need to remove ->groupBy() from query**

For example:

```
$solicituds = [];
foreach ($requests as $rq) { 
 $solicituds[] = $rq->solicitud;
}
```

Or

```
$solicituds = $requests->pluck('solicitud');
```

this will have an array of NON UNIQUE "solicituds".